# Windows Azure Authentication in Java

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, azure

Even though I checked previous answers towards azure authentication in java for web search, somehow I still get the HTTP Error Code: 401, even though the account key is exactly as is in my profile in Windows Azure Marketplace. I tried generating a new one but that didnt work either.

So any help would be very appreciated.

Here is the java code (similar to others that have used it):

```
String bingUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query='multiple'&$top=4&$skip=1&$format=json";

        String accountKey = "key";
        byte[] encoding = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
        String accountKeyEnc = new String(encoding);

        URL url = new URL(bingUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic ", accountKeyEnc));

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
          System.out.println(inputLine);
        sb.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
        System.out.println( sb.toString());
```

And the error code that i get is:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
>   https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query='multiple'&$top=4&$skip=1&$format=json
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at queryengines.WebSample.DisplayResults(WebSample.java:37)
>     at queryengines.WebSample.main(WebSample.java:19)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java expert, but shouldn't you change the String.format call to this?

```
String.format("Basic %s", accountKeyEnc)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem even though before I tried it on my Ubuntu machine and didn't work, but in Windows that seemed to be the problem.

Strangely in Ubuntu maybe the https protocol was causing this issue I suspect.

Comment: Yes it was exactly that, now I see that previously I didnt put the %s after 'Basic'. This seemed to fix it. Thanks a lot for the quick reply.